# How to stop browser to download "application/json" AJAX response as a file

Tags: javascript, browser

My firefox downloads the JSON response of an AJAX call as a file.
It's suppose to be handled by the JavaScript i.e. JSON object. 
Can anyone explain how to stop this behavior or there is something I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code that downloads the data.

Comment: What are the headers with which the file gets send? (E.g., look in Firebug's Net panel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may be making a regular POST instead of an xhr call.

Comment: I think you are right, I am using AJAX upload with using the POST in another frame I guess.

Comment: @codemeit: We can only confirm if you show us your source code…

Answer (score 1):

If you mean calling a script that returns plain JSON directly from Firefox [JsonView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869/) is a nice Plugin for viewing JSON responses in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was not related to the ajax, but the code later on. After ajax javascript was redirecting the browser to the same url. And firefox suggest you to open json response as a file.